# How to eliminate # of columns in a pipe delimited file, in vim

Tags: vim

I have a pipe-delimited file I am working with in Vim, how can I eliminate columns using this? For example - deleting everything before the third pipe on every line of the file

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

1. If your pipe delimited lines start at line #1, move the cursor to line #1,
   and press `Shift-o` (letter 'o') to add a blank line above your first line.
2. Make sure the cursor is in the new first line. Press

   `q a`

   to start to record your key stroke series into register 'a'. (`q` - start to
   record; `a` - record to register 'a')
3. Press

   `j d 3 f | q`

   (`j` - down; `d` - delete; `3` - the 3rd pipe; `f` - find; `|` - pipe sign; `q` -
   finish recording)
4. Press

   `u`

   to undo the deletion.
5. Check how many lines are there all together, say, 1000.
6. Move the cursor back to the first line, then press

   `1000 @ a`

   (`1000` - run the recorded key stroke series 1000 times; `@` - run the recorded key
   stroke series; `a` - in register 'a')

   You have achieved what you want.

**Method 2**

`:%normal 0d3f|`

Please read the help for `normal`
`:h normal`

Comment: Please format your markdown with proper syntax, e.g.,  inline code. Plain text is not good for reading.

Comment: @jdhao Thank you for reminding that! Certainly, I have formatted them.